# How to fix bad pattern issue in bash_profile?

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh, dotfiles

I'm getting a bad pattern output in my terminal:

```
   ➜  ~  source .bash_profile
load_dotfiles:1: bad pattern: files=(\n        /Users/xeLL/.rvm/scripts/rvm # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/bash_options # Options\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/bash_exports # Exports\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/bash_aliases # Aliases\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/functions/* # Functions\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/bash_prompt # Custom bash prompt\n        /Users/xeLL/.dotfiles/shell/bash_paths # Path modifications\n        /usr/local/etc/bash_completion # Bash completion (installed via Homebrew)\n        /Users/xeLL/.bash_profile.local # Local and private settings not under version control (e.g. git credentials)\n    )
   ➜  ~
```

This is part from bash_profile:

```
load_dotfiles() {
declare -a files=(
    $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/bash_options # Options
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/bash_exports # Exports
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/bash_aliases # Aliases
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/functions/* # Functions
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/bash_prompt # Custom bash prompt
    $HOME/.dotfiles/shell/bash_paths # Path modifications
    $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion # Bash completion (installed via Homebrew)
    $HOME/.bash_profile.local # Local and private settings not under version control (e.g. git credentials)
)

# if these files are readable, source them
for index in ${!files[*]}
do
    if [[ -r ${files[$index]} ]]; then
        source ${files[$index]}
    fi
done
```

}

Any thoughts on this?
Also I'm using oh-my-zsh and OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your listing (removed the '$(brew --prefix)'line) and changed:

```
source ${files[$index]}
```

to

```
echo "source ${files[$index]}"
```

Your function works fine on my Linux system.  So how to locate the issue/resolve?

1. any 'hidden' codes in your script? ## cat -v ~/some_bash_profile | more
2. bash -n ~/some_bash_profile # Bash will complain if errors
3. source each line manually # work ok?

Comment: Thanks for response Dale!
1. http://pastebin.com/gXHB5K1F
2. no errors
3.  nothing wrong
all configuration is here: https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/dotfiles

I found out that this only happens with zsh configuration.